# Rename bulk files with given name, in directory and subfolders using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I’m looking for a solution to rename all files with given name in the directory and subfolders.

E.g.
There is a directory called `c:\blah` and in this folder, there is one file called `BaR.txt` and one folder called foo. In the `foo` folder, there is another file called `bAr.txt`. 
I want to find all files with name `bar.txt` and change the name of each file to “neo.txt”. It must also be possible to rename the files to lower case as well e.g. `bar.txt`.
So far, I’ve tried to do this manually using the Windows Explorer in Windows10 but for some weird reason when I try to rename the bulk files there is extra “(1)” sign added to the end of each file name.
I’ve tried to play with PowerShell and I created a command

```
$_.name -replace 'bar.txt','neo.txt'
```

But it didn’t work for me.

Comment: this is not a _powershell_ answer ... but there is a tool that is _wonderful_ for this use. it's this `Introduction - Bulk Rename Utility — https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php`, and it is really handy. however, it will require getting approval, so you may still need to use PoSh instead.

Comment: Thanks for a tip, I also found an app called AdvanceRenamer https://www.advancedrenamer.com/ it's for free, you can quite easily make a search thing in the Windows Explorer, then select all the files from result and drag and drop everything to advanced renamer. Then you can do the rename thing using this program. Done. However, the PowerShell srcipt seems to be the fastest method.

Comment: the PoSh solution **_is_** the way to go for automation. [*grin*] the BRU app has a screen that looks like one of the regex "how to" sites. lots of fields that you can use to make different types of changes - plus, it has it's own file browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need 2 cmdlets: `Get-ChildItem` and `Rename-Item`.

This should work:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Blah' -Filter 'bar.txt' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName 'neo.txt'
}
```

However, if inside the `foo` folder there are more subfolders, this code will rename all files called `bar.txt` (case-insensitive) it finds in all of these subfolders.

If you do not want to go any deeper than the first subfolder in `C:\Blah` (the one called `foo`), you can use the `-Depth` parameter on the command like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Blah' -Filter 'bar.txt' -Recurse -Depth 1 | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName 'neo.txt'
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, ta!